# How to list the fonts, colors and sizes are used in a Word document?

Tags: microsoft-word, fonts

I have converted a very large PDF document to .docx file using Microsoft Word. The result has been good, but I have found some artifacts that I need to remove through the find and replace function.

It would be useful for this purpose to have a list of the fonts, colours and sizes that are used in the document. How could this task be done?

Comment: You'll probably need to write a macro. Here is a good starting point: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5261108/list-fonts-used-by-a-word-document-faster-method

Comment: check out https://stackoverflow.com/a/57055682